# Getting the title of button that was touched

Tags: iphone, ios, c

I have three buttons on my iPhone app and would like to programmatically access the title of the button that was touched.

Answer (score 0):

In your button's action method just use sender.currentTitle.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the target/action pattern ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html)), the argument to the action, typically named "sender," will be your button. You can programmatically access the button's properties from there.